# Using API in Swift (Postman,Alamofire,SwiftyJson)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, postman, swifty-json

I have an admin panel which admin can insert question and gives 3 options of answers to users to choose. The admin is able to insert questions according to different chapters...its like  a quiz game..The correct answer is then given an int value so in my collection of 3 buttons, I am able to know which is the correct button user has chosen. But now my problem is, in my Postman:

[image]

in my swift code

```
   func getaQuestionaByaChapter(chapterName: String,question: String, answer1: String, answer2 : String, answer3: String, answer: Int, completion: @escaping (JSON?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "secret_key" : "b3370e1590a2cf2b430e8cf8a8b361bd",
        "_action" : "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER",
        "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER" : chapterName,
        "question" : question,
        "option1" : answer1,
        "option2" : answer2,
        "option3" : answer3,
        "answer" : answer
    ]
```

is this a declaration correct?

as for my storyboard:
[image]

and after this, i would be doing

```
button1.setTitle = answer1
questionlabel.text = question
```

in my swift file for the part where i link my API

```
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

public class  EduappRestClient {

enum ContentType: String {
    case json = "application/json"
    case jpeg = "image/jpeg"
    case formEncoded = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    case none = "" //Content type will be empty
}

private static let url: URL = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.127:81/project/Online_Question/API/actiona")! //NSURL depreciated now using URL)

//singleton
static let sharedClient: EduappRestClient = EduappRestClient()

class func request(with url: URL,
                   method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                   parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                   contentType: ContentType = .json,
                   encoding: ParameterEncoding = JSONEncoding.default,
                   additionalHeaders: [String: String] = [:],
                   completion: @escaping(JSON?, Error?) -> Void
    ) {

    //MARK: Configure Headers
    var headers: [String: String] = [:]

    //if contenttype is specified as none type, leave content-type header field empty
    if contentType != .none {
        headers["Content-Type"] = contentType.rawValue

    }
    for (key, value) in additionalHeaders {
        headers[key] = value
    }

    Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        guard response.result.error == nil, let value = response.result.value else {
            completion(nil, response.result.error)
            return
        }

        let jsonData = JSON(value)
        completion(jsonData, nil)
    })
}

//MARK: - Getting questions by chapters
func getaQuestionaByaChapter(chapterName: String,question: String, answer1: String, answer2 : String, answer3: String, answer: Int, completion: @escaping (JSON?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "secret_key" : "b3370e1590a2cf2b430e8cf8a8b361bd",
        "_action" : "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER",
        "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER" : chapterName,
        "question" : question,
        "option1" : answer1,
        "option2" : answer2,
        "option3" : answer3,
        "answer" : answer
    ]

    let URLString = EduappRestClient.url

    EduappRestClient.request(with: URLString, method: .post, parameters: parameters) { (json, error) in
        guard error == nil, let json = json else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        let result: JSON = json[1]

        //result will print
        //"question": [
        // {
        //"question": "10+10",
        //"chapter_name": "Chapter 2",
        //"option1": "10",
        //"option2": "20",
        //"option3": "30",
        //"answer": "20"
        //}
        //]
        completion(result, nil)
    }
}}
```

it will show my data accordingly??

Comment: What issue you are facing

Comment: i need to show my label and button titles according to what i set from my admin panel. as you can see, in my postman, it's chapter 2, and question is 10+10. option one is 10,two is 20 and option three is 30. the correct answer is option 2, which means it's button [1] as i have put three buttons in one collection. now, from my code, the button titles and label text arent showing. I am unsure why

Comment: Can you show me your code, after checking I will let you know

Comment: Ok, let me try...pasting the codes in comments here?

Comment: You can upload your code to Github and then share

Comment: here u go https://github.com/WilliamLoke/quizApp

Comment: have added them , sorry references were messed up

Comment: I have added my suggestions in answer, can you please check

Answer (score 1):

**After API response, you have to use.**

```
class QuestionModel: Codable {
    let questions: [Details]
}

class Details: Codable {
    let question: String?
    let chapter_name: String?
    let option1: Int?
    let option2: Int?
    let option3: Int?
}
```

> And after this, you have to parse the response in the model data:

```
func getaQuestionaByaChapter(chapterName: String, completion: @escaping (QuestionModel?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "secret_key" : "b3370e1590a2cf2b430e8cf8a8b361bd",
        "_action" : "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER",
        "GETQUESTIONBYCHAPTER" : chapterName
    ]
    let URLString = EduappRestClient.url

    EduappRestClient.request(with: URLString, method: .post, parameters: parameters) { (json, error) in
        guard error == nil, let json = json else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(QuestionModel.self, from: jsonData)
            completion(result, nil)
        } catch let message {
            print("JSON serialization error:" + "\(message)")
        }
    }
}}
```

> Then in QuizViewController: You have to set the data:

```
EduappRestClient.sharedClient.getaQuestionaByaChapter(chapterName: "Chapter 2", completion: { (response, error) in

    //json is the result from rest client

   let firstQuestion = response?.questions.first
    self.questionsLabel.text = firstQuestion?.question
    self.answerButtons.setTitle("\(firstQuestion?.option1)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    self.answerButtons.setTitle("\(firstQuestion?.option2)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    self.answerButtons.setTitle("\(firstQuestion?.option3)", for: UIControlState.normal)
})
```

Comment: ok, so that means i would need to delete my Question class file, make a new file QuestionModel, and then declare the function and lastly set the data as your codes?

Comment: Yes, you can try and let me know if anything stuck.

Comment: have edited the codes, but in my EduAppRestClient, there is an error, and the buttons are showing it doesnt have subscripted members??have commited and pushed to Github. TQ so much for helping out

Comment: Remove 1,2,3 from answerButtons, updated my answer, please chek

Comment: there is an error which wrote : Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(JSON?, Error?) -> Void' in my model data

Comment: Updated my answer, Please check. You need to use do catch when decoding.